# Can't run ibeacon app but has no error in the code

Tags: java, android, ibeacon

I'm doing a project with ibeacon using Eclipse to build an APP , I import some codes from Android beacon library for detecting UUID ,  with no error in the codes , I try to open the apk on HTC device, but failed to open the App . 
Here is my code. Any help or suggest is appreciated.

```
package com.example.goooooood;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconConsumer;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconParser;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.MonitorNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Region;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public abstract class MainActivity extends Activity implements BeaconConsumer {
protected static final String TAG = "MonitoringActivity";
private BeaconManager beaconManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                    setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
            beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    // To detect proprietary beacons, you must add a line like below corresponding to your beacon
    // type.  Do a web search for "setBeaconLayout" to get the proper expression.
    // beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
    //        setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
    beaconManager.bind(this);
}
@Override 
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    beaconManager.unbind(this);
}
@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    beaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
        Log.i(TAG, "I just saw an beacon for the first time!");        
    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
        Log.i(TAG, "I no longer see an beacon");
    }

    @Override
        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
        Log.i(TAG, "I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: "+state);        
        }
    });

    try {
        beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myMonitoringUniqueId", null, null, null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {    }
}}
```

Here is the logcat.
[logat  part 1 of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1coS.jpg) 
[logcat part 2 of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdwD4.jpg)

Comment: Without a logcat, I'm not sure what you want as a solution to properly run this code

Comment: Check your beacons properly whether they are in eddystone or Ibeacon mode@snowowl

Comment: What do you mean by "failed to open the app"?

Comment: You shouldnt take screenshots of your errors, but the ClassNotFoundException looks very explicit in what the error is...